# Making sense of $\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\Delta}{\Delta}$

Tags: real-analysis, dirac-delta

We can construct the Dirac delta function by taking a rectangle with width $\Delta$ and height $\frac{1}{\Delta}$, which has area $1$ for all $\Delta\neq 0$, in the limiting case $\Delta\rightarrow 0$. Then it makes sense that the Dirac delta has integral $1$ under this construction since $\Delta$ never actually equals $0$ in the limit. What if we apply the same reasoning in the limiting case $\Delta\rightarrow\infty$? Then still we have integral $1$, but this resulting function demonstrates the same behavior as the function $f(x)\equiv 0$ whose integral is $0$. At first glance this seems paradoxical, but I can see where that's not so accurate to conclude. Still, I'm having trouble reasoning with rigor here. Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: The function $\frac\Delta\Delta$ equals $1$ for every nonzero value of $\Delta$, and therefore every limit of $\frac\Delta\Delta$ (including the one you ask about) equals $1$. Now whether that has implications for other objects such as the Dirac delta "function" is a different question, since it's not always the case that the integral of a limit equals the limit of the integrals.

Comment: A rigorous way of rephrasing your observation is as follows: The distribution $T_{\Delta} \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $$T_{\Delta}(\varphi)=\frac{1}{\Delta}\int_{-\Delta/2}^{\Delta/2} \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),$$ converges to $0$ as $\Delta \to \infty$. There is nothing mysterious in this statement. Rather, it is simply telling that the unit mass escapes towards infinity and eventually evades any "mass-detecting mechanism" that can only see a finite region.

Comment: On the other hand, if we consider a "mechanism" that can actually feel an infinitely large region, it is possible to capture those mass escaping. Indeed, let $C([-\infty,\infty])$ be the space of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ having limit at infinity. Then by defining $T_{\Delta}$ on $C([-\infty,\infty])$ using the same formula as above, we get $$\lim_{\Delta\to\infty}T_{\Delta}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{-\infty}+\delta_{\infty})$$ in the following sense: $$\lim_{\Delta\to\infty}T_{\Delta}(\varphi)=\frac{\varphi(-\infty)+\varphi(\infty)}{2}, \quad \forall \varphi\in C([-\infty,\infty]).$$